# C# MVC 5 User.Identity.Name is null after SignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, identity

I am developing an MVC 5 app for my company, and I am stuck on how to customize my login style. Here we go...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string userType)
    {
        bool checkLDAP = AuthenticateUser("corp.mycorp.go.id", model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (userType== "01")
                {
                    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    var externalUser = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);
                    if (externalUser==SignInStatus.Success)
                    {    
                        string idUser = ValidationHelper.GetIdUser(User.Identity.Name);                        
                        string idRole = ValidationHelper.GetRoleCode(idUser);
                        SessionHelper.SetSessionObject("ActiveRole", idRole);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not registered.");
                        return View(model);
                    }

                }
                else if (userType== "02" && checkLDAP == true)
                {
                    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    ApplicationUser internalUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

                    if (internalUser != null)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(internalUser, false, 
                        string idUser = ValidationHelper.GetIdUser(User.Identity.Name);
                        string idRole = ValidationHelper.GetRoleCode(idUser);
                        SessionHelper.SetSessionObject("ActiveRole", idRole);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not registered.");
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Failed");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "));
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Failed");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I want to get the User Id with parameter `User.Identity.Name`

```
string idUser = ValidationHelper.GetIdUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

But all I get is null. How can I solve this?

Update :
Here my `AuthenticateUser` for userType 02

```
public static bool AuthenticateUser(string pDomainName, string pUserID, string pPassword)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string pServerMessage = "";
        DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", pDomainName), pUserID, pPassword);
        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dir);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + pUserID + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            search.FindOne();
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pServerMessage = ex.Message;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

For userType 01, I using default RTM authentication.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue, but you can use `User.Identity.GetUserId()` if you add the using statement `Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity` to get the user id if you're using ASP.NET Identity (as you are)

Comment: can you please update your question and show us `AuthenticateUser` function?

Comment: @Coulton negative sir. I was trying but the result is still same.

Comment: I agree with @Robert then, we need your AuthenticateUser implementation.

Comment: how about `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` instead of `User.Identity.Name` ?

Comment: @Robert so they are different?

Comment: @RianApriansyah Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @alisabzevari not yet bro, but I have another solution to override it..